# Modifying array property of PFUser - Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an array property called `courses` on my `User` table in Parse. Any idea why I might getting `Cannot modify user XTC9aiDZlL. code=206, message=Cannot modify user XTC9aiDZlL.` when I do the following:

```
user.remove('courses', deletedCourse);
user.save()
```

where `deleteCourse` is the course `PFObject` to delete

Comment: Are you doing this via cloud code? You could useMasterKey to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

Are you signed in as the user you're trying to modify? That can cause problems like this, as Parse usually just lets a user modify themself & the objects they've created.

If you're signed in as the same user you're trying to edit that's another story. This is a glitch that seems to be popping up in the Parse server recently. It's not the best solution but for now you'll need to modify the ACL when you create the user, like this:

```
let user = PFUser()
let acl = PFACL()
acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
acl.getPublicReadAccess = true
user.acl = acl
```